# 0x80071C57 Error Connecting to Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to deploy my application or connect to a Service Fabric cluster, but I get the following error: `Could Not connect to cluster: System.Fabric.FabricException: An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071C57`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurred because I did not have the correct client certificate installed on my dev box. Once I installed it, I was able to connect to the cluster in PowerShell and deploy apps in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue for me too. I expected a more user friendly message for a missing certificate.